# How to slice 2D Torch tensor individually per row?

Tags: python, pytorch, slice, tensor, torch

I have a 2D tensor in Pytorch that I would like to slice:

```py
x = torch.rand((3, 5))
```

In this example, the tensor has 3 rows and I want to slice `x`, creating a new tensor `y` that also has 3 rows and `num_col` cols.

What's challenging for me is that I want to slice different columns per row. All I have is `x`, `num_cols`, and `idx`, which is a tensor holding the start index from where to slice.

Example:
What I have is `num_cols=2`, `idx=[1,2,3]` and

```
x=torch.arange(15).reshape((3,-1)) =
tensor([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
```

What I want is

```
y=
tensor([[ 1,  2],
        [ 7,  8],
        [13, 14]])
```

What's the "torch"-way of doing this? I know, I can slice if I get a boolean mask somehow, but I don't know how to construct that with `idx` and `num_cols` without normal Python loops.

Answer (score 2):

You could use fancy indexing together with broadcasting. Another solution might be to use [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html) which is similar to numpy's `take_along_axis`. Your `idx` array would need to be extended with the extra column:

```
x = torch.arange(15).reshape(3,-1)
idx = torch.tensor([1,2,3])

idx = torch.column_stack([idx, idx+1])
torch.gather(x, 1, idx)
```

output:

```
tensor([[ 1,  2],
        [ 7,  8],
        [13, 14]])
```